# Reduction examples from the strongly NPC problem 3-PARTITION

Tags: reference-request, np-complete

3-PARTITION is [strongly NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_NP-complete), i.e. it remains NP-complete even if the input is given in unary.

I'm searching two or three examples of (possibly well-known) *non-numeric problems* that have been proved to be NP-complete using a reduction from 3-PARTITION (and the reduction obviously relies on the strongly np-completeness). I would like the references to the original papers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found two articles, both on Tetris.

The first one is [Tetris is Hard, Even to Approximate](http://erikdemaine.org/papers/Tetris_TR2002/paper.pdf) by Erik D. Demaine et al. It uses the unary encoding scheme for 3-Partition problem and constructs a polynomial reduction:

> The $a_i$'s and $T$ are represented in unary, so the size of the game is polynomial. (from Theorem 3.2, page 9)

The other one is [Tetris is Hard, Made Easy](http://www.liacs.nl/~kosters/tetris/tetr.pdf) by Ron Breukelaar et al. It also uses the unary 3-Partition problem:

> Note that the board is constructable in polynomial time (measured in the
>   input size), since the variables in the problem definition may be given in unary
>   due to the strong sense of NP-completeness (Theorem 1). On its constructibility,
>   consult [4]. (from section 2.3)

I did not go into the two articles. Are them qualified to your references request?

**EDIT:** I recently found another example of optimal scheduling of a job system with ordered precedence constraints on two dedicated processors. Here is the paper ["On the Complexity of Scheduling Problems for Parallel/Pipelined Machines" (IEEE Transactions on Computers 1989)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=00029469).

Comment: Nice! I found other examples like the Isomorphic Implication Problem, but they are not so popular ...

Comment: @Vor Another problem found recently is added.

Answer (score 4):

Prof. Erik Demaine has contributed the wonderful [(video) lecture](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.890/fall14/lectures/) of *"Algorithmic Lower Bounds: Fun with Hardness Proofs (Fall'14)"*. In particular, lectures 2 and 3 are devoted to the reductions (directly or indirectly) from $\textsf{3-Partition}$.

For example, Lecture 2 is concerned with several variants of Jigsaw puzzles. The results are collected in the paper [*"Jigsaw Puzzles, Edge Matching, and Polyomino
Packing: Connections and Complexity"*](http://erikdemaine.org/papers/Jigsaw_GC/paper.pdf). Its abstract says

> We show that jigsaw puzzles, edge-matching puzzles, and polyomino packing puzzles
>   are all NP-complete. Furthermore, we show direct equivalences between these three types of
>   puzzles: any puzzle of one type can be converted into an equivalent puzzle of any other type.

---

Most probably you have known these results and this video lecture. However the wonderful lecture may be also useful for other people.